# Fortify cleanse rule doesn't cleanse everything

Tags: c#, fortify

My team has recently started using Fortify Static Code Analyzer (version 17.10.0 156) on our .NET code base (C# 6 and VB.NET), and are experiencing some pain with the amount of false positives it reports. For any given issue we can't know if it is a false positive without looking at it, and we don't want any actual problems to get lost in the clutter.

We have a utilities library with a method `ReadEmbeddedSql` which extracts sql from resources embedded in the assembly to execute. Fortify flags any `OracleCommand` (from `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client`) which execute the sql returned from this method with a Sql Injection vulnerability. 
This vulnerability is reported at the point the sql is set on the command, be it via constructor, or via the CommandText property.

It does not do this if the `ReadEmbeddedSql` method is defined in the local assembly.

A pared down listing of the source code which produces this result follows below. In the example code, `ExecuteSomeSql()` and `ExecuteSomeSqlDifferently()` are flagged with a vulnerability where `ExecuteSomeLocalSql()` is not.

For Analysis Evidence it only lists the line the OracleCommand is created:
[image]

> TestDao.cs:27 - OracleCommand()
>
> RuleID: 31D4607A-A3FF-447C-908A-CA2BBE4CE4B7

in the details for the issue it provides:

> On line 27 of TestDao.cs, the method ExecuteSomeSql() invokes a SQL query
>   built using input coming from an untrusted source. This call could
>   allow an attacker to modify the statement's meaning or to execute
>   arbitrary SQL commands.

A sample diagram presented by Fortify for this issue:
[image: ExecuteSomeSql Diagram]

After much searching, I came across this post describing a similar problem and proposed solution: [Can I register a trusted source for SQL statements](https://community.saas.hpe.com/t5/Fortify-Questions/Can-I-register-a-trusted-source-for-SQL-statements/qaq-p/1558238%20%22Can%20I%20register%20a%20trusted%20source%20for%20SQL%20statements)

After following the instructions there, and verifying the instructions independently in a [different version of the user guide](http://file:///C:/Users/mxp026/Documents/HP_Fortify_Audit_Workbench_User_Guide_4.00.pdf) (page 90)

The result is unchanged. I added an additional 'SQL Injection Validation Rule'  rule which is specifically described as "... identifies a function that properly validates data before using them in a SQL query."

Still no avail.

EDIT:
I have played around with custom rules more, and have been able to determine that the CustomCleanseRules are actually being applied (they do remove other types of taint), but not removing some trust specific flag Fortify applies to our in-house library.

Every value returned from any method of my libraries is distrusted, and none of the rules I've created seem to be able to remove this distrust.

Is there something I am doing wrong, or does Fortify just not work?

Is there a different type of rule needed to cleanse this general distrust?

Example Source code:

In library:

```
namespace Our.Utilities.Database
{
    public abstract class BaseDao
    {
        protected string ReadEmbeddedSql(string key)
        {
            //... extract sql from assembly
            return sql;
        }
    }
}
```

In application:

```
namespace Our.Application.DataAccess
{
    public class TestDao: Our.Utilities.Database.BaseDao
    {
        public void ExecuteSomeSql()
        {
            //... connection is created
            // Fortify Does not trust sqlText returned from library method.
            var sqlText = ReadEmbeddedSql("sql.for.ExecuteSomeSql");
            using(var someSqlCommand = new OracleCommand(sqlText, connection)) // Fortify flags creation of OracleCommand as SqlInjection vulnerability.
            {
                 someSqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        public void ExecuteSomeSqlDifferently()
        {
            //... connection is created
            // Fortify Does not trust sqlText returned from library method.
            var sqlText = ReadEmbeddedSql("sql.for.ExecuteSomeSql");
            using(var someSqlCommand = connection.CreateCommand()) 
            {
                 someSqlCommand.CommandText = sqlText; //Fortify flags setting CommandText as SqlInjection vulnerability.
                 someSqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        public void ExecuteSomeLocalSql()
        {

            //... connection is created
            var sqlText = ReadEmbeddedSqlLocallyDefined("sql.for.ExecuteSomeSql");
            using(var someSqlCommand = new OracleCommand(sqlText, connection))
            {
                 someSqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        protected string ReadEmbeddedSqlLocallyDefined(string key)
        {
            //... extract sql from assembly
            return sql;
        }
    }
}
```

XML of custom rules:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RulePack xmlns="xmlns://www.fortifysoftware.com/schema/rules">
    <RulePackID>5A78FC44-4EEB-49C7-91DA-6564805C3F23</RulePackID>
    <SKU>SKU-C:\local\path\to\custom\rules\Our-Utilities</SKU>
    <Name><![CDATA[C:\local\path\to\custom\rules\Our-Utilities]]></Name>
    <Version>1.0</Version>
    <Description><![CDATA[]]></Description>
    <Rules version="17.10">
        <RuleDefinitions>
            <DataflowCleanseRule formatVersion="17.10" language="dotnet">
                <RuleID>7C49FEDA-AA67-490D-8820-684F3BDD58B7</RuleID>
                <FunctionIdentifier>
                    <NamespaceName>
                        <Pattern>Our.Utilities.Database</Pattern>
                    </NamespaceName>
                    <ClassName>
                        <Pattern>BaseDao</Pattern>
                    </ClassName>
                    <FunctionName>
                        <Pattern>ReadSqlTemplate</Pattern>
                    </FunctionName>
                    <ApplyTo implements="true" overrides="true" extends="true"/>
                </FunctionIdentifier>
                <OutArguments>return</OutArguments>
            </DataflowCleanseRule>
            <DataflowCleanseRule formatVersion="17.10" language="dotnet">
                <RuleID>14C423ED-5A51-4BA1-BAE1-075E566BE58D</RuleID>
                <TaintFlags>+VALIDATED_SQL_INJECTION</TaintFlags>
                <FunctionIdentifier>
                    <NamespaceName>
                        <Pattern>Our.Utilities.Database</Pattern>
                    </NamespaceName>
                    <ClassName>
                        <Pattern>BaseDao</Pattern>
                    </ClassName>
                    <FunctionName>
                        <Pattern>ReadSqlTemplate</Pattern>
                    </FunctionName>
                    <ApplyTo implements="true" overrides="true" extends="true"/>
                </FunctionIdentifier>
                <OutArguments>return</OutArguments>
            </DataflowCleanseRule>
        </RuleDefinitions>
    </Rules>
</RulePack>
```

Answer (score 1):

When I run your sample code (I do have to modify it since it will not compile as is).  When I run it with SCA 17.10 with 2017Q3 (I also did this on 2017Q2) I did not get a the same SQL Injection Rule ID as you.

Looking at your Analysis Evidence, I assume that the analyzer that found this was not Dataflow or Control flow but maybe the Semantic or Structural?

You can see the type of analyzer that found the finding by looking at the summary tab:

[image: Displaying the summary tab of Visual Studio Fortify plugin, highlighting the analyzer engine that found the specific issue selected.]

Either way, I don't think a Custom Rule is what I would do here.

An option you can do is to use a Filter file.

This a file that can contain

- RuleIDs
- InstanceIDs
- Categories

When this file is passed into the scan command, any finding that matches any of the fields in the filter file will be filtered out from the results.

You can find examples of using the filter file in `<SCA Install Dir>\Samples\Advanced\filter`

or you can look in the [Fortify SCA Users Guide](https://community.saas.hpe.com/t5/PDF-HPE-Security-Fortify/HPE-Security-Fortify-Static-Code-Analyzer-User-Guide/ta-p/1587846) in Appendix B: Filtering the Analysis

*Note: Your analysis of using filters (in comment) are spot on.

Comment: -1 Please try reading the question again, this answer gets almost everything about this scenario wrong, and reads as 'Do that thing you said you already did and isn't working like it should.' 1. Fortify is not complaining about what is coming out of the database, but what is going in.(A vulnerability is reported where the sql is set on the command, not where it is executed, and not where the results are used(no results used). I've added an example and comments to hopefully better demonstrate this.) 2. The problem I'm reporting is **Even with the rule**, Fortify is not trusting the sql.

Comment: 3. Fortify is not showing where the 'tainted' input is coming from. (I've added screenshots for the Analysis Evidence and Diagram to better demonstrate this.) 4. No vulnerability reported for `ExecuteSomeLocalSql` and `ReadEmbeddedSqlLocallyDefined`  5. 'Write additional cleanse rules' Again the problem reported is that the cleanse rules don't cleanse the distrust. I know I put a lot of information into my questions, but it is because I want to make it clear what I have already attempted. How can I make that more clear?

Comment: Thanks for the second look/update. I did look at filters but had decided against using them because they seem like either an overly broad brush (silence a particular rule, or category) or more work than not doing anything (if filtering on issue number, the issue has to show up before it can be filtered, so still has to be examined on a per-issue basis.

Comment: Turns out your assumption about the analyzer was spot on: These are being triggered by the semantic analyzer, and that would be why the dataflow rule doesn't help. Which analyzer wasn't displayed anywhere I could find in the application (Visual Studio plugin), and only showed up on the BIRT report.